# OOM when allocating tensor with shape[204800,256]

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

In my docker, I am running 4 AI models. With a client, I'am executing them in series. After the third model being executed, i receive following error below:

```
 Found 10 images belonging to 1 classes.
2020-11-16 14:36:25.527713: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-11-16 14:36:25.527759: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:312] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-11-16 14:36:25.527797: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (8483c5677aa4): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-11-16 14:36:25.545885: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:104] CPU Frequency: 2297335000 Hz
2020-11-16 14:36:25.546449: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f93c822d520 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-11-16 14:36:25.546470: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Found 10 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 10 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 10 images belonging to 1 classes.
2020-11-16 14:36:35.338572: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at cwise_ops_common.h:134 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[204800,256] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
Log:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/common/program/AINET_common.py", line 23996, in process_client_observer_command
    process_client_command(command)
  File "/app/common/program/AINET_common.py", line 23970, in process_client_command
    status = deploy_generate_prediction()
  File "/app/common/program/AINET_common.py", line 24790, in deploy_generate_prediction
    model_height,model_width,model_depth,model_dir,model_loss,model_optimizer,model_data_type)
  File "/app/common/program/AINET_common.py", line 5939, in loadmodel
    model = load_NN_model(file_json,file_h5)
  File "/app/common/program/AINET_common.py", line 5974, in load_NN_model
    model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/model_config.py", line 122, in model_from_json
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 175, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 358, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2239, in from_config
    config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 617, in from_config
    config, custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 1204, in reconstruct_from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 1186, in process_layer
    layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 175, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 358, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 488, in from_config
    model.add(layer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 221, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 926, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1098, in _functional_construction_call
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 2643, in _maybe_build
    self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py", line 1178, in build
    trainable=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 614, in add_weight
    caching_device=caching_device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 750, in _add_variable_with_custom_getter
    **kwargs_for_getter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 145, in make_variable
    shape=variable_shape if variable_shape else None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 260, in __call__
    return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 221, in _variable_v1_call
    shape=shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 199, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2597, in default_variable_creator
    shape=shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 264, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 1518, in __init__
    distribute_strategy=distribute_strategy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 1651, in _init_from_args
    initial_value() if init_from_fn else initial_value,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/initializers/initializers_v2.py", line 397, in __call__
    return super(VarianceScaling, self).__call__(shape, dtype=_get_dtype(dtype))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops_v2.py", line 561, in __call__
    return self._random_generator.random_uniform(shape, -limit, limit, dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops_v2.py", line 1044, in random_uniform
    shape=shape, minval=minval, maxval=maxval, dtype=dtype, seed=self.seed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py", line 307, in random_uniform
    result = math_ops.add(result * (maxval - minval), minval, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 339, in add
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6843, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[204800,256] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu [Op:Add]
```

First I tried with this docker cmd:

```
docker run --rm -it -e TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
```

Later, I tried with this docker cmd:

```
docker run --rm -it -e TZ=Europe/Amsterdam --cpu-shares 4000 --cpus 3.0
```

Probably it is something easy to solve that I don't know or see right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I was running several containers. Loading in all my AI models by default in the application container wasn't the best idea. I made my library Docker image, used by the application container, smaller and only load 1 AI model at the time(whenever I need it) in the application image of Docker.

A big help for analysing was the Docker commando here was: **docker stats**

Answer (score 0):

Last line of error say that you dont have enough RAM to store the parameters of the model. either make model smaller or increase RAM.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I'am having 16GB ram available. The application is only using 1300 MB. This is something I noticed: as long I stay under a usage of 1024 MB RAM, the Docker application doesn't crash. The moment I go over that number, the application falls off. Does anybody know about limitation for a single Docker container of 1024 MB RAM you can maximum use?